# How do I find out if a file exists on a local file system in VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

In my new extension, i need to find value for `valeCLI.config` from another extension, save it to a variable, override it temporarily with a custom value, and when deactivating the extension, return the value back.
I'm trying out the following, i know there's a lot of troublesome code as i'm learning by mistakes :-)

```js
const vscode = require("vscode");
var oldValeIniPath = false;

function activate(context) {
    // get config obj for vale plugin
    let valeConfiguration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("vale");
    // get the current .vale.ini path
    let currentValeIniPath = valeConfiguration.get("valeCLI.config");
    // get info about old vale.ini
    let oldValeIniType = vscode.workspace.fs.stat(currentValeIniPath).type;
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(oldValeIniType);
    if (oldValeIniType) {
        let oldValeIniPath = currentValeIniPath;
    } else {
        let oldValeIniPath = "";
    }
    let suseValeConfigPath = context.extensionPath;
    valeConfiguration.update("valeCLI.config", suseValeConfigPath + "/.vale.ini");
}
exports.activate = activate;
// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() {
    valeConfiguration.update("valeCLI.config", oldValeIniPath);
}
exports.deactivate = deactivate;
```

Can somebody give me a hint please? Also, a good tutorial how to debug VSCode extension link would be great.

Comment: why did you ask this question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76514633/11107541